# Dynamically change ID of a HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, html

```
<% @level1.each do |row1| %>
<table id="tbl_main1" name="tbl_main1">
    <tr>
        **<td><a href="javascript:toggle_visibility('tbl1','lnk1');">**
            **<div align="right" id="lnk1" name="lnk1" width="2%">[+]</div></a></td>**      
    </tr>
    <tr>
                 **<table id="tbl1" name="tbl1">**
                <tr><td height="0.5" bgcolor="#EEEEEE"></td></tr>
                   </table>
    </tr>
</table>
<% end %>
```

I want am creating multiple tables on runtime using a loop in Ruby. But I want to change the id's of 'link1' and 'tbl1' dynamically such that each table has a unique 'tbl' name and 'lnk1' name.

Comment: Then you should make your Ruby code do that. No reason to do it dynamically in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% @level1.each_with_index do |row1, index| %>
  <table id= <%= "tbl_main#{index}" %> name="tbl_main1">
```

will do what you want I think.

Comment: It still doesn't append the ruby code to the id. I think this syntax is not correct.

Comment: Sorry, out of the habit of using erb, I normally use haml at the moment. I think the edit should have fixed it.

Comment: It did change the id's in the table and the hyperlink. But when it does not change the arguments when i pass it to the javascript function

Comment: You need to learn about string interpolation - a good place to start is http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/rails-flavored-ruby#sec-strings

Answer (score 3):

You can use some element of row1 to do so.
Pseudo code below:

```
<% @level1.each do |row1| %>
<table id="tbl_main1#{row1.id}" name="tbl_main1">
    <tr>
        **<td><a href="javascript:toggle_visibility('tbl1#{row1.id}','lnk1#{row1.id}');">**
            **<div align="right" id="lnk1#{row1.id}" name="lnk1" width="2%">[+]</div></a></td>**      
    </tr>
    <tr>
                 **<table id="tbl1#{row1.id}" name="tbl1">**
                <tr><td height="0.5" bgcolor="#EEEEEE"></td></tr>
                   </table>
    </tr>
</table>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I think you mistakenly left `table id="tbl_main1"` unchanged inside your loop.

Comment: @Blazemonger : I do not want to change anything in tbl_main1. There is a hyperlink (+) in tbl_main, which expands another table(tbl1) which resides in a row in tbl_main. I want to change the id of the hyperlink and the tbl1 dynamically. I can append the value of 'row1' which i get from my ruby code. But I am not sure of the syntax to append a ruby variable to a html id.

Comment: You can't (well, shouldn't) have two elements with the same ID in a single HTML document. Any JavaScript or internal anchors will find the first one and never look for the second one. Those IDs should be created unique before they're ever sent to the browser.

Comment: No i mean I can append the row1 value to the lnk and tabl1....that would make thier id's different from each other.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment above, you should change your code to do this. There is no reason for relying on client-side scripting or code modification when you simply can change your code to fulfill your need right away.

So, instead of using

```
id="lnk1"
```

you should be using

```
id=someDynamicVariableInYourCode
```

Besides, if you could explain why you need this and what you are trying to achieve with this, it would be much easier to understand what you want.

Comment: I want to learn how to attach my ruby variable to the html id. I am not aware of the syntax of that.

Answer (score 0):

the exact syntax would be something like this :

```
<td><a href="javascript:toggle_visibility('<%= "tbl1#{index}" %>', '<%= "lnk1#{index}" %>');>
......
......
div align="right" id=<%= "lnk1#{index}" %> name="lnk1" width="2%">[+]</div></a></td>
...... 
......
<table id=<%= "tbl1#{index}" %>
```